# Setting header Authorization for https get request in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a client that consumes a rest API with header Authorization. I'm getting a hard time getting to work adding http header authorization. I'm using the code below:

```
package com.javap;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            sslUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            //InputStream input = null;

            InputStream input = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("./application.properties");
            prop.load(input);

            String address = prop.getProperty("address");
            String token = prop.getProperty("token");

            URL url = new URL(address + customerId);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",  "Bearer " +  token);

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");


            conn.connect();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                hasSQ = "false";
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }else {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
                while(sc.hasNext()){
                    inline += sc.nextLine();
                }
                sc.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

I get an error of 401. But using Postman, everything works fine, son it's defiintely not about the token. Any ideas on how this could be resolved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code looks fine for sending the bearer token. But this part `sslUtil.turnOffSslChecking();` rings some alarm bells.

Comment: If it working fine on **Postman**, Then you can take code or header help from **Postman** . Go to Postman Right corner near **Save** drop-down button there is a option link called **code** . Click on It, It display you how **Postman** apply code for your API.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Apparently the connection was a success but I'm reconnecting to the webservice again via url.openStream() without the attached header authorization. That's why. My bad :-p

Thanks.